# Convert JSON to map with string keys and List<String> values

Tags: dart

I'm attempting to convert JSON that has strings for keys and string arrays for values.

From my understanding, this *should* work:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var jsonString = '{"key": ["1", "2", "3"]}';
  var data = json.decode(jsonString) as Map;
  var result = data.cast<String, List<String>>();
  print(result);
}
```

However I get the error that `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast`.

What's interesting, however, is that the following does correctly work:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var jsonString = '{"key": "value"}';
  var data = json.decode(jsonString) as Map;
  var result = data.cast<String, String>();
  print(result);
}
```

So, I assume that the `.cast<>` method introduced with Dart 2 doesn't know how to convert nested types that aren't simple types like `String`, `int`, or `bool`.

How would I convert this object to a `Map<String, List<String>>` without resorting to external libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, I assume that the `.cast<>` method introduced with Dart 2 doesn't know how to convert nested types that aren't simple types like String, int, or bool.

That's correct. It just does a one-level-deep shallow conversion. You can do the nested conversion yourself like:

```
void main() {
  var jsonString = '{"key": ["1", "2", "3"]}';
  var data = json.decode(jsonString) as Map;

  var result = data.map((key, value) =>
      MapEntry<String, List<String>>(key, List<String>.from(value)));
  print(result.runtimeType);
}
```

This is calling `Map.map()`. Sometimes `Map.fromIterable()` or `Map.fromIterables()` is a better fit. The collection types have a handful of methods like this to convert between different types.